# Disabled click effect on parent button when nested span is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf

When I click on the question mark, the button parent has the click effect (here blue color)
Is it possible to disabled it ?

```
    <h:commandLink  
      styleClass="btn btn-primary btn-lg"
      style="width: 100%;">
      <span class="fa fa-trash"/>
      <span id="spanQuestion"
            class="fa fa-question"
            data-content="Help"
            data-html="true" 
            data-popover="true"/>
    </h:commandLink>
```

```
    const span =  $('#spanQuestion');
    span.on("click", function(e) { 
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
```

[Not clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZLVy.png)

[When the question mark is clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oJR1.png)

I tried to stop the click on the parent, add background-color.
I expect not to have click effect on the parent button.

Comment: Seems like a css issue. Can you inspect it and determine what's causing the blue color?

Comment: It's only the blue color from bootstrap

Comment: How is the *blue color from bootstrap* being applied? Can you override that?

Comment: @mykaf good idea. I add $(".btn-primary").css('background-color',"white") in the function and now I have a white background hiding the icon. I think that I must add an opacity

Comment: Do you have other items with class `btn-primary` that this could affect?

Comment: Yes, here is just a test.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="myButton" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" style="width: 100%;">
    <span class="fa fa-trash"></span>
    <span id="spanQuestion" class="fa fa-question" data-content="Help" data-html="true" data-popover="true"></span>
</a>
<script>
    const button = $('#myButton');
    const span = $('#spanQuestion');

    span.on("click", function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });

    button.on("click", function (e) {
        // Your button click logic here
    });
</script>
```

Comment: While your code may be correct, your answer is not considered to be a "good" answer here at Stack Overflow. You should explain what the original problem was and how your code solves it.

Comment: I'll already try this. It's not working

Comment: Here the button parent is grey. Its original color is blue.
Its a boostrap button.
What's happen if you click on a button ? His color becomes darker like my exemple